# Example notebook, sample for google cloud pipeline component

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am looking for a sample or a tutorial notebook with specifically the "CustomPythonPackageTrainingJobRunOp" google cloud pipeline component. I have been trying to use this but keep getting into errors.

PS: I have already posted a question about the errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795098/error-when-trying-to-use-custompythonpackagetrainingjobrunop-in-vertexai-pipelin) and also requested a sample, but posting again regarding the sample since I feel that that is a pretty long post and the request is buried with other code details.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any reference documents or sample code for your requirement.

From your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795098/error-when-trying-to-use-custompythonpackagetrainingjobrunop-in-vertexai-pipelin), I can understand that you’ve resolved the argument error in the “CustomPythonPackageTrainingJobRunOp”.

**Feature Request**

However if you would still require a documented approach, you can let Google know that this is a workflow that is important and that you would like to request they provide a sample code for it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues?q=assignee:poojs@google.com%20status:open) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. I'd suggest you make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [AI & Machine Learning](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=187220&template=1161235), with the Feature Request template.

Comment: Thanks, don't need a sample anymore as I resolved the error as you saw.